# Underscore - _.every implementation

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming, underscore.js, implementation

#### Implementing the _.every method

I am trying grasp how the below code implements every.

```
_.every = function(collection, iterator) {
    var check = iterator || _.identity;

    if (collection.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    // check if any are falsy

    return _.reduce(collection, function (prev, next) {
        if (!prev) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return check(next) ? true : false;
        }
    }, true);
};
```

I'm familiar with reduce and how it accepts the `accumulator` as the last `argument`, but I've yet to see a `bool`passed as that argument.

Also the `if` statement in reduce is kinda confusing, because `reduce` will pass the accumulator, in this case it's `true`, as the first argument in the `iterator` for reduce. So:

`if(!prev)` really means `if(!true)`, and if it is not true then return false.

will that end the reduce function? or will it then move to the else statement?

Any help clarifying whats happening in this code, or a better example of how to implement `_.every` would be appreciated.

Comment: *if it is not true* - then go to the else part

Comment: You don't seem much familiar with reduce. I suggest reading the [underscore documentation](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: doesn't seem like a good method because it still iterates every array element, even though it knows the answer will be false. it would be better to stop iteration as soon as an answer is known. a worst-case: `_.every(Array(999999), fn)` would loop a million times...

Comment: Where did this code come from? The body of the `reduce` can just be `return prev && check(next);`. Also, `check` should be called with `(elt, idx, arr)` for compatibility. The `collection.length` check might be a micro-optimization but is not necessary.

Comment: @torazaburo: you have to see the rest of the underscore source, it's more readable than anything else, even if that means not being the most concise. it also is NOT SUPPOSED to be compat with native Array methods.... (no skipping sparse sections, no `this` application on method callbacks, etc)

Comment: I just checked the underscore source, and it looks nothing like what you have shown. See http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-30.

Comment: @torazaburo The implementation was found online. I am looking for the most vanilla javascript implementation to wrap my head around.

Comment: I suggest you find another vanilla implementation. This one is severely flawed, primarily in the way that it fails to short-circuit on the first falsy result, which is one of the key features of `every`.

Comment: @torazaburo thank you for pointing out the flaws with the code. It was my goal to this kind of feedback so I can implement this function correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reduce function calls its function argument for every element of the input collection. `prev` is true the first time the anonymous function inside reduce gets called, but not necessarily the second and third time.

For example, assume `every` gets used to check whether all invoices in a database are paid. If the second out of a thousand invoices is not paid already, there is no need to contact the database server for the third and further elements.

By first checking whether `prev` is false already (and thus the result will be false), this implementation circumvents the need to go further. Arguably, upon detecting false, the function could even stop processing right there and not go any further, but alas `reduce` does not offer that option.

For instance, assume we call `_.every([1,2,3,4,5,6], function(i) {return i < 3;});`:

```
 accumulator | input | result | check called?
=============================================
 true        | 1     | true   | yes
 true        | 2     | true   | yes
 true        | 3     | false  | yes
 false       | 4     | false  | no
 false       | 5     | false  | no
 false       | 6     | false  | no
```

The accumulator is the parameter to `reduce` (`true`) in the first round, and in later round it's the result of the previous round. The result of the whole function is the final entry of the `result` column.

`return check(next) ? true : false;` is short for

```
if (check(next)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Alternatively, one may write simply `!!check(next)`. The effect of all three versions is the same - convert `check(next)` to boolean.

Another way to write the whole function would thus be:

```
_.every = function(collection, iterator) {
    var check = iterator || _.identity;
    return _.reduce(collection, function (prev, next) {
        return prev && !!check(next);
    }, true);
};
```

Here we use the [short-circuit operator `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) to much the same effect. Note that we can safely drop the check of `collection.length === 0`, since reduce will simply return the initial accumulator (aka `memo`).

As mentioned above, even faster would be to abort once we know the result will be false (note that this specific version may only work for arrays):

```
_.every = function(collection, iterator) {
    var check = iterator || _.identity;
    for (var i = 0;i < collection.length;i++) {
        if (! check(collection[i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

That is the implementation (albeit somewhat de-simplified) we [see in](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L248) [the wild](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L479).

Comment: Wow, a very concise answer. Thank you. Makes the reduce function much easier to grasp. I am now only struggling with the last portion of the code, the `else check(next) ? true: false`. I get that the `?` operator performs a test for truth or false. And that if the identity/iterator(prev) === true, then return true. But will the if statement run again if the else statement does return true?

Comment: just read your updated comment, thanks for the clarification on the `!!check(next)`

Comment: I have updated the answer with a more detailed explanation about that part of the code.